# Error logging in for osx

Tags: h2o

This is a continuation of

https://community.h2o.ai/questions/2165/error-logging-in.html
and 
**https://community.h2o.ai/questions/1665/can-not-login-to-steam-osx.html**

from my original post on community.h2o:
"""
Hi there, I am currently trying to set up an an API on my local machine using steam.
The documentation is out of date on http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/Installation.html#steam-start-flags which says to start the steam service for the first time, execute ./steam serve master --admin-name=admin --admin-password=admin the first time around to set the password. The current command is ./steam serve master --superuser-name=admin --superuser-password=admin but when I try to log in to 0.0.0.0:9000 (which is what it asks me to point the browser to) I get 2017/06/14 13:03:48 User admin does not exist I tried using single, double and no quotes.
Thank you for your time!
"""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default username/password is superuser/superuser. The flags are not honored by steam server command and looks like its a bug. See config.toml file in the folder.

This breaks the very first developer experience with h2o/steam and is not encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

./steam serve master --superuser-name=superuser --superuser-password=superuser works fine